# Set segmentation fault handler

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In my signal.h file I have added a signal handler like this:

```
#define SIG_WPG ((__sighandler_t)3)
```

and then implemented it in signal.c like this:

```
if (ka->sa.sa_handler == SIG_WPG) {
        unsigned long ul_cr2 = current->tss.cr2;
        unsigned long ul_eip = (unsigned long) regs->eip
        int ul_cr2_rounded = ul_cr2 & PAGE_MASK;
        printk("ul_eip: %d\n", ul_eip);
        printk("ul_cr2: %d\n", ul_cr2);
        printk("ul_cr2_rounded: %d\n", ul_cr2_rounded);
    }
```

How can I make this signal handler handle segmentation faults in user space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to define:

```
static struct sigaction segv_action
```

and then set:

```
segv_action.sa_handler = SIG_WPG;
```

This was for a University project, these changes were done in a .c file we got from the school, so there may be other details needed that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `signal()` method to register a callback for that exception:

```
//callback prototype
void Handler(int sig);

//register the callback for the specific signal
signal(SIGSEGV,&Handler);
```

Comment: Can you give an example? I tried with signal(SIG_WPG); which gives me an error about making integer from pointer without a cast.

Comment: @JacobOJ have you tried what I suggested? Btw, signal is used to register a callback, not to send a signal to the application.

Comment: Im not sure how to use it. How does handler know to use SIG_WPG?

Comment: Is it a handler for a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) or SIG_WPG? If you want a handler for SIG_WPG, just replace SIGSEGV with SIG_WPG, i.e. signal(SIG_WPG, &Handler); Handler(int sig) will be called whenever the signal SIG_WPG is received. Don't know how to be any clearer than that.

Comment: I want to run the code in signal.c when there is a SIG_WPG, not a user implemented handler. Maybe I'm asking the wrong questions. I am rather confused about all of this :)

Comment: @JacobOJ so put the code in signal.c inside void Handler(int sig) and register the method via signal. You're saying it doesn't work?

Comment: I got it to work using segv_action.sa_handler = SIG_WPG; Thank you for your time.

Comment: @JacobOJ you should post your solution as an answer and accept it. Others might experience the same problem, and a solution would be welcomed.

Comment: Will do :) It tells me to wait 7 hours though.

Comment: @JacobOJ ok. I'll leave my answer up as a reference.